# Как подсчитать какой шанс выпадения числа в random.uniform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, теория-вероятностей

Имеется простенький код который проверяет число на выпадение. но как мне узнать шанс, и сколько попыток нужно для этого выпадения?

```
import random
for x in range(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999):
    r = str(random.uniform(0.0000001, 1))
    if r[8] == '1' and r[7] == '0' and r[6] == '0' and r[5] == '0' and r[4] == '0' and r[3] == '0' and r[2] == '0' and r[1] == '.' and r[0] == '0':
        print(r)
```

Comment: Вот это задача! Класс! Автор всех обвёл вокруг пальца!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не столько о Python, сколько о том, как считать вероятности, при этом с неожиданным для кого-то выводом:-) (но на результат Python повлияет изрядно). Судя по вопросу, спрашивает школьник, кто это не проходил пока, тогда обойдемся без умных формул.
Но для начала предлагаю совершенно непитоническую строку поменять на её нормальный эквивалент - легче понять, что хотим. Да и начальное условие тоже поменяем на более читаемое, так как явно речь идёт о бесконечном цикле.

Внимание: учитывая ответ @Stanislav Volodarskiy ниже, необходимо изменить желаемую последовательность для сравнения, чтобы совпадение было иногда. Например, на  1000001.

```
import random
while True:
    r = str(random.uniform(0.0000001, 1))
    # Первые два символа - всегда '0.' И вместо 0000001 поставлено 1000001.
    if r[2:9] == '1000001':
        print(r)
```

Итого, видим, что речь идет о совпадении всех 7 символов.

Шанс на совпадение одного - 1 к 10 (1 нуль после 1). Значит, вероятность совпадения всех семи - 1 к 10 000 000 (семь нулей после 1) - один к десяти миллионам.

Попыток надо усреднённо - тоже десять миллионов, но так как генератор случайный (условно, на самом деле - псевдослучайный), то может совпасть с первой попытки, а может не совпасть никогда (если у псевдослучайного генератора это число не выпадает в течение периода последовательности).

Comment: @quessy-dev, если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)

Comment: Если есть шесть нулей, то на девятом месте не может быть нуля. Значит вероятности выпадения отдельных цифр зависимы и их нельзя перемножать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, но не понятно. Первая фраза объясняется ответом про научный формат или это что-то другое? (так теория ниже и семь девяток вполне себе равны моей единице с семью нулями).

Comment: Я имел ввиду что комбинация `0.0000000` не возможна, так как генератор порождает значения от `0.0000001`. А вы эту комбинацию учитываете при вычислении вероятности.

Comment: Спасибо, да, вы совершенно правы, тут уже психологии больше, чем математики. У меня 9 999 999 и 10 000 000 лежат в одной и той же ячейке с точки зрения вероятности, я это вообще выкинул, написав, что без формул обойдемся, но для математика, наверное, это совсем разное. И да, возможно, автору вопроса это тоже может быть важно, если это в школе задали, а не игрушку пишет.

Comment: quessy-dev - спасибо, но мне достаточно +1 поставить, а принять с галкой и +1 надо ответ @StanislavVolodarskiy, пожалуйста. Это он нашел и написал, что "в научном формате на первой позиции не бывает нуля". Иначе мы бы с вами долго ждали выполнения условия:-) И все комментарии советую почитать - интересная переписка получилась:-)

Answer (score 1):

### Теория

Условие сводится к тому что случайное число выглядит как: `0.0000001...`. На месте точек могут быть любые цифры. Следовательно, по условию случайное число должно лежать в полуинтервале `[0.0000001, 0.0000002)`.

Равномерный случайный генератор порождает числа в интервале `[0.0000001, 1]`. Из равномерности следует что вероятность печати числа равна отношению длин интервалов:

> ```
> (0.0000002 - 0.0000001) / (1 - 0.0000001) ~=
> ~= 1.0000001 * 10^-7 (равенство примерное)
> ```

Так как нас интересует как часто мы будем получать такие числа, нам нужна обратная величина. Нужное число будет получаться в среднем через `9999999` попыток. Это точный результат.

### Практика

Числа меньшие `0.0001` в Питоне преобразуются в строку в научном формате:

> ```
> @>>> str(0.0001)
> '0.0001'
> @>>> str(0.00009)
> '9e-05'
> ```

А в научном формате на первой позиции не бывает нуля - порядок так подбирается чтобы первой цифрой была единица или больше. Поэтому вы никогда не дождётесь срабатывания условия.

Comment: Просьба уточнить - речь идет только про печать, как вывод в `stdout`, или про внутреннее представление тоже? В строковой переменной r тоже окажется научный формат? (интуитивно мне кажется, что не должно бы так быть, но интуиция у меня не из Python). Автор ведь не про печать спрашивает, а про совпадение. печать у него просто как индикатор совпадения стоит.

Comment: В переменой `r` окажется строка в научном формате и дальнейшая проверка провалится.

Comment: Да, верно, проверил даже. Символы в `r` со второго по пятый никогда не равны  '0000'. Изменил свой ответ. Я-то ещё удивился, запустив программу утром, когда ответ писал, и не увидев выпаданий числа, но решил, что преувеличил скорость работы машины, да и уходить надо было. А сейчас, заменив 0000001 на 1000001, за пару минут 5 совпадений получил.